# Why does this file prevents me from merging my branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-lfs

I have a Git repo with LFS installed and working properly. On my `dev` branch, I renamed an image file (tracked by LFS) from `NoMedal-Fade.png` to `None-Fade.png` with the Windows file Explorer. I committed, pushed onto GitLab, and it went great.

Then, in another instance of this repo on my computer (this repo is on another branch called `production/foo`, I ran `git fetch`, and `git merge origin/dev` to get and merge the modifications I just made in the other instance. This is where I have troubles understanding what's happening: the merging failed with this error:

```
error: add_cacheinfo failed to refresh for path '■■■■/■■■■/■■■■/■■■■/■■■■/■■■■/None-Fade.png'; merge aborting.
```

And this added the new file in the unstaged modifications:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   ■■■■/■■■■/■■■■/■■■■/■■■■/■■■■/None-Fade.png
```

In my incomprehension, I tried to `git reset --hard`, but the file was still here. I tried to `git checkout <file path>`, but the file was still here. I deleted the instance, cloned back, and tried again the same process, still same problem. I tried to stage the file I wanted to have, committed it and pushed it. Now the file doesn't show up anymore in the unstaged files list, but i still can't merge because of this same error aforementioned (`add_cacheinfo`). Finally, a friend of mine told me to try `git config core.fscache false` before merging, unfortunately, nothing changed (same for global config).

```
PS C:\Users\■■■■> git --version
git version 2.24.0.windows.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the only thing I found was to reset the branches before the file was renamed, with `git reset --hard <commit hash before rename>` and `git push origin <remote branch>:<local branch> --force` to update the remote.

---

**WARNING:** keep in mind that this latter command is very dangerous if you work with several people. Given that I'm the only one with a friend on this project, it was easy to tell him to clone the project back and avoid bigger errors.

---

After having erased from the history the faulty commits, I renamed the file once again with `git mv <file name> <new file name>` instead of using Windows' file explorer. It worked well, apparently, I have no more issue with the file.

But still, this is not a real solution to the issue, more like a workaround. I'll keep my answer as the best solution until someone finds something else.